# MSSQL Server performance metrics in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a project where i need to display the database mssql server's performance metrics for example memory consumed/free, storage free space etc. I have researched for this purpose and one thing came up was [DOGSTATSD](https://github.com/DataDog/dogstatsd-csharp-client).

`Datadog` provides the library for .net project to get custom metrics but that was not the solution for me because the metrics works on datadog website. I have to display the all (in graph or whatever suited) data, received from MSSQL SERVER. There will be multiple servers/instances.

Is there a way to do that, our WebApp connected with multiple databases and we receive/display information.

I cannot use already available tools for the insights.

Comment: You can easily get all needed data via quering dmv and other resources inside sqlserver. Good start is here:https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-march-2018/

Comment: @revoua thanks for the link, its good to have some idea about the implementation.

Comment: Why close vote, care to explain so i can either remove or edit the question ?

Comment: @revoua i think its good idea if you post it as answer.

Comment: You need that in order to optimize your code/queries or it is for final users to see?  I use Glimpse to optimize developed code and queries.

Comment: @Romias thanks for the reply, it is for final users to see only, its only read operations to check the database servers status

Comment: The close vote seems to because your question is too broad, and it is, you just say "I have to display the all data, received from MSSQL SERVER" -- that's huge amount of data. You should really describe what you mean with "performance metrics" -- anyhow like others have suggested, most likely all the data is available with some sort of queries, part of them might be quite hard to figure out, and some of them require you to do some sort of sampling / storing of previous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get all needed data via querying dmv and other resources inside SQL Server. Good start is [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-march-2018/).